# Retrieving data from three tables using joins

Tags: sql

I have the following tables:

```
Post (id, title, author_id) etc
Tags
Post_tags
Author
```

The following sql query only seems to get the first thread, along with *all* the tags.

```
SELECT post. * , author.username,
GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT tag.name ORDER BY tag.name DESC SEPARATOR ',' ) AS tags
FROM author, post
JOIN post_tags ON post.id = post_tags.thread_id
JOIN tag ON post_tags.tag_id = tag.id
WHERE author.id = post.author_id
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You usually use `GROUP_CONCAT()` with a `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: And the title should say **four** tables

Comment: Yeah I changed that as soon as I created it, you were looking at the (mem?)cached version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You usually use `GROUP_CONCAT()` with a `GROUP BY` clause.

Without a `GROUP BY`, it means it will group ALL rows into one and thus show the group concatenation of ALL tags.

The first thread data that you see is a byproduct of MyQSL ill-behaviour that allows you to show fields in the SELECT that are not dependent on the grouping fields (none in your case).

Try your query adding `GROUP BY post.id` at the end.

```
SELECT post. *
     , author.username
     , GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT tag.name ORDER BY tag.name DESC SEPARATOR ',' )
         AS tags

FROM author
  JOIN post
    ON author.id = post.author_id
  JOIN post_tags
    ON post.id = post_tags.thread_id
  JOIN tag
    ON post_tags.tag_id = tag.id

GROUP BY post.id
```